# client-go creating a Pod with configmap as volume

Tags: go, kubernetes, configmap, client-go

I'm implementing an admission webhook which is supposed to add a sidecar container, config for which needs to be picked from a `configmap`
As the current flow stands, the `configmap` is assumed to exist in the cluster and I need to just `VolumeMounts` it.
I'm trying the following piece of code in client-go :

```golang
pod.Spec.Volumes = append(pod.Spec.Volumes, corev1.Volume{
        Name: "startup-config",
        VolumeSource: corev1.VolumeSource{
            ConfigMap: &corev1.ConfigMapVolumeSource{
                v1.LocalObjectReference{
                    Name: "my-configmap",
                },
            },
        },
    })
```

However I'm getting a `too few values in "k8s.io/api/core/v1".ConfigMapVolumeSource literal`  error
Since the `configmap` object already exists in the cluster, I don't want/need to provide any other fields apart from the `Name` of `configmap`
What am I missing here?
ps: The docs mention all other fields in `ConfigMapVolumeSource` as optional.
I want to achieve something as simple as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
```

> YAML manifest is just an eg. of what I want to achieve

Comment: your problem is located in `&corev1.ConfigMapVolumeSource{
 "Whichproperty?": v1.LocalObjectReference{ Name: "my-configmap", }, },`

Comment: this are not some random error the compiler throws for the fun, they contains line number to help you identify the source of your errors, just saying.